# Reference on two numbers associated to a module of finite homological dimension

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$ with a module $M$ which has finite projective dimension and finite injective dimension.

Let $n \geq 1$.
Let $(P_i)$ be a minimal projective resolution of $M$ and $(I_i)$ a minimal injective coresolution of $M$.
Let $u_M^n:=dim(P_0)-dim(P_1)+dim(P_2)-dim(P_3)+....+(-1)^n dim(P_n)$ and $t_M^n:=dim(I_0)-dim(I_1)+dim(I_2)-dim(I_3)+...+(-1)^ndim(I_n)$ ($n$ might not be the projective/injective dimension of $M$ but smaller).

> Question: Is there a name for the numbers $u_M^n$ and $t_M^n$ associated to $M$? Have they been studied in the literature?

Comment: Aren't they just equal to $dim(M)$? I must be missing something.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I made the question more precise by adding an $n$ (which might be smaller than the projective dimension).